# Syntax of AngularJS Filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

For my angularJS 1.3 application I use this structure at bottom. 
It would be great if someone could give me a hint if someone is wrong with this syntax:

[AngularJS Structure](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#table-of-contents)

and currently I am not sure if this is the right syntax for a filter:

(function() {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('my.project')
    .filter('datesFilter', datesFilter);

datesFilter.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'api_config', 'anotherService'];

function datesFilter($http, $q, api_config, anotherService) {
    return function (items, extrafilter) {
        // do something
    };
}
```

})();

Comment: Why don't you... test it, and ask only if you have a problem?

Comment: Because I am a beginner and therefore I am searching for help.

Comment: And that is my help. You have defined a filter. I assume you know how to use a filter. If not, read the angular documentation about filters. Then try using your filter, and see if it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually dont understand if there is a problem or not.
The syntax for an angularjs filter would be like stated in [AngularJS dev guide](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.19/docs/guide/filter)

```
angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(input, uppercase) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      out = input.charAt(i) + out;
    }
    // conditional based on optional argument
    if (uppercase) {
      out = out.toUpperCase();
    }
    return out;
  };
})
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'hello';
}]);
```